# Geting data in between specific column variables in python

Tags: python-2.7, date, datetime

I'm trying to get all of the data in this data frame (DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME) that are In between this time 09:04:00 and 09:25:00.

I really appreciate any help and your time,

here's the csv

DATE,TIME,OPEN,HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,VOLUME 02/03/1997,09:04:00,3046.00,3048.50,3046.00,3047.50,505
02/03/1997,09:05:00,3047.00,3048.00,3046.00,3047.00,162
02/03/1997,09:06:00,3047.50,3048.00,3047.00,3047.50,98
02/03/1997,09:07:00,3047.50,3047.50,3047.00,3047.50,228
02/03/1997,09:08:00,3048.00,3048.00,3047.50,3048.00,136
02/03/1997,09:09:00,3048.00,3048.00,3046.50,3046.50,174
02/03/1997,09:10:00,3046.50,3046.50,3045.00,3045.00,134
02/03/1997,09:11:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.00,3045.00,43
02/03/1997,09:12:00,3045.00,3045.50,3045.00,3045.00,214
02/03/1997,09:13:00,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,3045.50,8
02/03/1997,09:14:00,3045.50,3046.00,3044.50,3044.50,152
02/03/1997,09:15:00,3044.00,3044.00,3042.50,3042.50,126
02/03/1997,09:16:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,128
02/03/1997,09:17:00,3042.50,3043.50,3042.50,3043.50,23
02/03/1997,09:18:00,3043.50,3044.50,3043.00,3044.00,51
02/03/1997,09:19:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.00,3043.00,18
02/03/1997,09:20:00,3043.00,3045.00,3043.00,3045.00,23
02/03/1997,09:21:00,3045.00,3045.00,3044.50,3045.00,51
02/03/1997,09:22:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,47
02/03/1997,09:23:00,3045.50,3046.00,3045.00,3045.00,77
02/03/1997,09:24:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,131
02/03/1997,09:25:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.50,3043.50,138
02/03/1997,09:26:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,6
02/03/1997,09:27:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.00,3043.00,56
02/03/1997,09:28:00,3043.00,3044.00,3043.00,3044.00,32
02/03/1997,09:29:00,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,3044.50,63
02/03/1997,09:30:00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,3045.00,28
02/03/1997,09:31:00,3045.00,3045.50,3045.00,3045.50,75
02/03/1997,09:32:00,3045.50,3045.50,3044.00,3044.00,54
02/03/1997,09:33:00,3043.50,3044.50,3043.50,3044.00,96
02/03/1997,09:34:00,3044.00,3044.50,3044.00,3044.50,27
02/03/1997,09:35:00,3044.50,3044.50,3043.50,3044.50,44
02/03/1997,09:36:00,3044.00,3044.00,3043.00,3043.00,61
02/03/1997,09:37:00,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,3043.50,18

Thanks for the time

Comment: Use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the datetime column as index and then use `between_time()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fn, parse_dates=[[0, 1]], index_col=0)
df.between_time("09:04:00", "09:25:00")
```

Comment: Thanks It's always something that easy just hard to find I guess. Really appreciate it!